# Redirect 301 With Matching Parameter .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I am redirecting a website from old traditional (m.) url to responsive design url .

Here is my example of the url and htaccess.

```
Old traditional URL => New Responsive design URL 

m.mydomain.com => mydomain.com
m.mydomain.com/mobiles.html => mydomain.com/mobiles
m.mydomain.com/mobiles/android-phones.html => mydomain.com/mobiles/android-phones-price.html
m.mydomain.com/mobiles/android/samsung-phones.html => mydomain.com/mobiles/samsung/android-phones.html
```

### .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301  m.mydomain.com/mobiles/android/(.*)-phones.html mydomain.com/mobiles/$1/android-phones.html
```

But i am getting Internal Server Error (500) . 
How to Fix this issue.

Comment: When you get an internal server error, step 1 is: Check the Apache error log.

Comment: I am not really familiar with RedirectMatch, but you can try the following: Capitalize the M in `RedirectMatch`. Make the 3rd argument of `RedirectMatch` an actual url. That is: including a protocol.

Comment: I changed to 'RedirectMatch' Even though getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot match host name using `RedirectMatch` directive.** Use `mod_rewrite` rules instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mydomain.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mobiles\.html$ http://mydomain.com/mobiles [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mobiles/android-phones\.html$ http://mydomain.com/mobiles/android-phones-price.html [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mobiles/android/samsung-phones\.html$ http://mydomain.com/mobiles/samsung/android-phones.html [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Nice series of rules, +1. Hope it works for Raaga. :)